# Despite of GRADLE_HOME variable set, IntelliJ keeps asking for Gradle Location

Tags: intellij-idea

I have `$GRADLE_HOME` environment variable set on my machine (Fedora Linux):

```
$ echo $GRADLE_HOME                                                     
/home/michal/opt/gradle-4.9
```

and gradle executable is on path:

```
$ gradle -version                                                      

------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 4.9
------------------------------------------------------------
```

yet IntelliJ IDEA (Ultimate Edition, 2018.1.5 and older versions) fails to find Gradle location. How do I fix this?

Comment: For project IDE uses the Gradle that you set in [import from gradle wizard](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/gradle.html#project_create_gradle) dialog or in File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle if it is an existing project. IDE does not use GRADLE_HOME environment variable.

Comment: Thanks for this. It is a bit odd that IntelliJ allows choose a path to Maven for a default project (i.e. newly ones) but it doesn't allow to choose a path to Gradle.